# Repl.it unable to install pandas

Tags: pandas, replit

I'm trying to install pandas on `Repl.it` but I keep getting this message.

```
Using version ^1.2.4 for pandas

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies...

[AssertionError]

exit status 1


Repl.it: Package operation failed.
```

[Full Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JGsY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Broken package installs can usually be fixed by,

1. Updating `pip` and installing pandas from PyPI. By default, `Repl.it` comes with `pip` version `19.3.1`, but the latest available version for `python 3.8` is `pip-21.1.1`.

   ```
   ~/repl$ pip -V
   pip 19.3.1 from /opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
   ~/repl$ pip install pandas
   Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.5 in /opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas) (1.20.2)
   Collecting pytz>=2017.3
     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/70/94/784178ca5dd892a98f113cdd923372024dc04b8d40abe77ca76b5fb90ca6/pytz-2021.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
   Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in /opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.1)
   Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas) (1.15.0)
   Installing collected packages: pytz, pandas
   Successfully installed pandas-1.2.4 pytz-2021.1
   ```

   [image: Command line interface showing how to install the pandas package into replit]
2. Update poetry and re-install pandas using poetry.

   ```sh
   # Remove the project packager files
   rm pyproject.toml poetry.lock
   # Update
   poetry self update
   # Install pandas
   poetry add pandas
   ```
3. Review the server backend availability. `Repl.it` runs on Google Cloud Platform services. We can check the [REPL.it status page](https://status.replit.com) or [the REPLIT Twitter account](https://twitter.com/Replit) to see if Repl.it is having a GCP backend service outage. If they haven't updated recently, they may be responding to an unreported outage. Check [Google's own GCP status page here](https://status.cloud.google.com). You can also Tweet at [the CEO of Repl.it here](https://twitter.com/amasad), @amjad-masad on Stackoverflow.